# Javascript Check the form data is changed or not when submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a edit form which is showing the selected check boxes , when submitting i want to check that either is there any change in the check boxes or not?

Comment: Compare their current checked status against the `defaultChecked` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the current value of each of the checkboxes with their original setting. For this you can compare the [`checked`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp) property with the [`defaultChecked`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_defaultchecked.asp) property.

Here is some code:

```js
function wasAnyCheckChanged() {
    return $('input[type=checkbox]').toArray().some(function(el) {
        return el.checked != el.defaultChecked;
    });
}

// At submission: collect them again and compare
$('form').submit(function() {
    if (wasAnyCheckChanged()) {
        alert('you changed checks');
    } else {
        alert('No changes made');
    }
    return false; // cancel submission
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" checked>Option 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk2" >Option 2<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
```

This code shows an alert indicating whether any of the checks were different at submission than as they were at page load. Then the submission is cancelled. You could decide what to do, and only cancel the submission in one of the two cases.

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you give some feed-back?